# PHP script to remove e-mail addresses from a comma-separated list

Tags: php, mailing-list

I run a small website and my users requested that I set up a mailing list. I found a simple free script that adds e-mail addresses to a protected text file, `email.txt`, in CSV format:

```
email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,blah,blah,blah
```

The script works flawlessly. However, it is a nuisance to go through the file to manually remove e-mail addresses when users cancel their list subscriptions. I need to create a simple script that removes e-mail addresses.

All I want is a simple PHP script that displays a text box so users can enter their e-mail addresses and click a "Cancel Newsletter" button. The script should search the text file, find the given e-mail address and remove it and its trailing comma.

For example, say the contents of `email.txt` are

```
john@yahoo.com,peter@yahoo.com,steve@yahoo.com
```

If I type "peter@yahoo.com" into the text box displayed by my desired script, I want the file to look like this:

```
john@yahoo.com,steve@yahoo.com
```

**UPDATE**: I tried this code:

```
<?php
        function showForm() {
            echo '
            <form method="post" action="">
            Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">
            </form>
            ';
        }

        $_POST['email']

        $to_delete = 'email';
        $file = array_flip(explode(",",file_get_contents("email.txt")));
        unset($file[$to_delete]);
        file_put_contents("email.txt",implode(",",array_flip($file));

        if(!$file_put_contents) {
            die('Error occured');
        } else {
            echo 'Your subscription has been cancelled. You will not receive any further emails from us.';
        }
    }
} else {
    showForm();
}
?>
```

This code doesn't even show the form.

**UPDATE 2**:

Another attempt at writing this script:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $text = file_get_contents("email.txt");
    $oldWord = "$email";
    $newWord = "";
    $text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $text);
    $fp = fopen('email.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

This works as far as removing the e-mail address goes, but there is no announcement (echo). I would like for it to say either "that e-mail isn't subscribed" or "you have been removed," based on whether the script sucessfully finds the `$email` in the list and deletes it.

**UPDATE 3** Dec. 31, 2011:

I tried the advanced code and just got a blank page, so I went back to my version. Here is the code I have now:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $basetext = file_get_contents("email.txt");
            $oldWord = "$email";
            $newWord = "";
            $text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $basetext);
            $str1 = $basetext;
            // echo strlen($str1);
            $str2 = $text;
            // echo strlen($str2);
            $fp = fopen('email.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $text);
            if ($str1 > $str2) { // This part handles the success/fail message
                echo ("Success!");
            } else {
                echo ("Fail!");
            }
            fclose($file);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly. However, it displays the "fail" message when the page is loaded, not when triggered to load, after the submit button is pressed.

I would like to keep the original code if possible, just rearranged so that it only shows "Success!" or "Fail!" once it has executed the code.

I would like the echo messages to be the last script executed on the page.

Comment: [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/)

Comment: It looks like you should have a parser error with your `$_POST['email']` line.

Comment: how would you suggest i code this to remove errors? thanks mate

Comment: have just tried the code you modified, and still nothing.... just blank screen

Comment: very greatful thanks mate, but im baffled with this, only ever done very basic php

Comment: The $_POST['email'] is not assigned to anything or checked, and does not end in a `;`, so it would be a parser error either showing you an error message or rendering a blank page if error reporting is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer was originally appended to the question body by the OP.*

First I moved the form to `/cancel.html` and used `<form action="/cancel_submit.html">`.

(Where I have written `.html`, it is just to demonstrate, as my server is configured to use no page extentions and also so that PHP is parsed on `.html` pages.)

Then I put the PHP code into the page `/cancel_submit.html` and moved

```
if ($str1 > $str2) {
    echo ("You Have Successfully Unsubscribed From Our Newsletter....<br>You Will Not Receive Any More Emails From Us.");
} else {
    echo ("The Email Address You Specified Is Not In Our Mailing List.");
}
```

to another set of PHP brackets.

This meant that the e-mail adddress was sent via POST to the other page, which then performed the actual removal of the e-mail address from the list and then checked to see if an address been removed to provide the comfirmation message.

I also added two commas to `$oldword = "$email";` to make it `$oldword = ",$email,";` so that it only finds the text entered into the e-mail box if it has a comma on either side. This addresses the case where someone submits half of an e-mail address.

I also changed `$newWord = "";` to `$newWord = ",";` so that if the script removes an e-mail address with commas at each side, the two e-mail addresses that were next to it will not be separated by a comma.

Here is the code I have for both pages now:

1. cancel.html

   ```
   <p>To cancel our Newsletter please enter your email address below....</p>
   <p>
   <form method="post" action="/cancel_submit.html">
   <p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">
   </form>
   ```
2. cancel_submit.html

   ```
   <?php
       $email = $_POST["email"];
       $basetext = file_get_contents("email.txt");
       $oldWord = ",$email,";
       $newWord = ",";
       $text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $basetext);
       $str1 = $basetext;
       // echo strlen($str1);
       $str2 = $text;
       // echo strlen($str2);
       $fp = fopen('email.txt', 'w');
       fwrite($fp, $text);
       fclose($file);
   ?>
   <?php
       if ($str1 > $str2) {
           echo ("You Have Successfully Unsubscribed From Our Newsletter....<br>You Will Not Receive Any More Emails From Us.");
       } else {
           echo ("The Email Address You Specified Is Not In Our Mailing List.");
       }
   ?>
   <p>
       <p>Please wait to be re-directed or <a href="http://the-flying-shuttle.com/"><u>CLICK HERE.</u></a>
       </p>
   ```

**EDIT**:

I made a few improvements. I added:

```
$email = strtolower($email);
```

to both the e-mail add script and the e-mail remove script. This converted all characters entered into either form to lowercase; previously, it wouldnt remove e-mails typed in a different case than the big list had.

This messed up the confirmation message command, so I changed it to

```
if (str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $basetext)) {
    echo ("You Have Successfully Unsubscribed From Our Newsletter....<br>You Will Not Receive Any More Emails From Us.");
} else {
    echo ("The Email Address You Specified Is Not In Our Mailing List.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why you don't use a database?

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (`address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`address`)) ENGINE=InnoDB
INSERT INTO `emails` VALUES ('user1@example.com')
SELECT * FROM `emails`
DELETE FROM `emails` WHERE `address`='user1@example.com'
```

These are just infinitely easier and more efficient than a text file...

But if you want to use a text file...

```
$to_delete = 'user1@example.com';
$file = array_flip(explode(",",file_get_contents("email.txt")));
unset($file[$to_delete]);
file_put_contents("email.txt",implode(",",array_flip($file));
```

Basically what it does it explodes by the comma, then flips the array so that the emails are keys (and their numeric positions are values, but that doesn't matter), then it removes the email you want to delete and finally reassembles the file. The bonus of this is that it will also strip out any duplicates you may have.

You can use a similar method to add email addresses, just changing the `unset` line to `$file['user1@example.com'] = -1;` (to ensure the number doesn't conflict with anything, as that would interfere with the array flipping).

Comment: On the second example, wouldn't a `str_replace($email, '', $emailtxt)` work, with maybe a `str_replace(',,', ',', $emailtxt)` to cleanup? (Or I suppose a regex so it's all on a single line...)

Comment: the reason i dont use a database is because i have many bots trying to access random phpmyadmin directories in access logs.... this is only a small site, and i know that php is fully capable of working with flat files to save the complications of databases and being hacked....

Comment: Yes, it would, but my way keeps duplicates out at all times.

Comment: oops wasnt meant to post that yet.... its more hassle than its worth securing mysql just for a simple mailing list.....

thanks for your quick reply and i am going to test the code now ,

Comment: That is a very bizarre reason for not using a database. a) you don't need phpMyAdmin, b) phpMyAdmin requires the database's username and password, c) you can rename the default phpMyAdmin folder to `herp-a-derp-derp` and nobody would be any the wiser. EDIT: You keep sniping me :p If this is all you'd be using it for, then I guess you're right about it not being worth it.

Comment: *[str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)* Also, [`str_ireplace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) would handle email addresses with varying capitalization.

Comment: how would i link the 'user1@example.com' into the form that would have the text box?

Comment: `$_POST['email']`, assuming your text box has `name='email'`.

Comment: ok thanks will give it a bash now, im not the best at php coding, im more adept at html

Comment: @DJ-P.I.M.P - If you're going to use a flat file, make sure it's not web-accessible. You want to prevent someone/something from downloading your mailing list.

Comment: its already secure, but thanks for the advice

Comment: this is the first time i have used this site, and i cannot paste code in this comment box so have edited original question

Comment: i think ive killed it.... any ideas @Kolink

Comment: `$to_delete = $_POST['email'];` is what you need, and remove that stray `$_POST['email'];` above it.

Comment: thanks mate, tried that and i just get a blank page..... i have come across this before, on another script, if there are any errors it wont even display the form, so i am baffled

Comment: @Kolink hey mate ive kinda sussed it, still stuck tho if u can help plz

Comment: @JaredFarrish hey jared mate i got code working but a little stuck still if u can help plz mate

Answer (score 0):

Suggested research:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
edited to add:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

If you end up with a 3rd party service, don't pay Aweber. Go for [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/). They've got a free plan if your mailing list isn't that big.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you reference a variable `$_POST['email']` without assignment or testing the value.  Additionally you may want to sanitize this variable.

Another issue I saw was that `$to_delete = 'email';`, you are only looking for entries of 'email'.

Your `$file_put_contents` is not being assigned.

`} else { showForm(); }` wasn't paired up with an if statement.

```
<?php
function showForm() {
    echo '<form method="post" action="">' . PHP_EOL
       . 'Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"> <br />' . PHP_EOL
       . '<input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">' . PHP_EOL
       . '</form>';
}

if($_POST['email']) {

    $to_delete = $_POST['email'];
    $file = array_flip(explode(",",file_get_contents("email.txt")));
    unset($file[$to_delete]);
    $file_put_contents = file_put_contents("email.txt",implode(",",array_flip($file));

    if(!$file_put_contents) {
        die('Error occured');
    } else {
        echo 'Your subscription has been cancelled. You will not receive any further emails from us.';
    }
} else {
    showForm();
}
```

Comment: hi mate ive had some luck but still stuck, ive edited original question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are attempting to achieve.

- Check to see if the user has posted from a form.

  - Get the email.  (You should ensure that it is a sane value in this step)
  - Retrieve the member data.
  - Check to see if the user is on the list.

    - Remove the user and save the data if applicable.
  - Output the result of the function.
- Display a message with form to submit to self.

I know this can be done as a very simple task, but I don't trust that approach.  Additionally, I think anything interacting with permanent storage of data should have some mild to moderate form of abstraction.

I would approach that task this way.

```
class MailingList {

    const EMAIL_OK = 1;
    const ERR_EMAIL_EXISTS = -1;
    const ERR_EMAIL_INVALID = -2;
    const ERR_EMAIL_NOTFOUND = -3;

    protected $_db_src;
    protected $_db_opt;
    protected $members = array(); // An array intended to hold members.

    public function email_exists($email) {
        return array_key_exists($this->members, $email);
    }

    public function remove_email($email) {
        $this->_sanitize_email($email);

        if ($email) {
            if (array_key_exists($this->members, $email)) {
                unset($this->members[$email]);
                $this->_update_members();
                return self::EMAIL_OK;
            } else {
                return self::ERR_EMAIL_NOTFOUND;
            }
        } else {
            return self::ERR_EMAIL_INVALID;
        }
    }

    public function add_email($email) {
        $this->_sanitize_email($email);

        if ($email) {
            if (array_key_exists($this->members) {
                return self::ERR_EMAIL_EXISTS;
            } else {
                $this->members[$email] = -1;
                $this->_save_members();
                $this->_load_members();
                return self::EMAIL_OK;
            }
        } else {
            return self::ERR_EMAIL_INVALID;
        }
    }

    // We expect a data source and options for the
    //     data source upon instantiation.
    // This is to prepare this class for abstraction and allow it to be
    //     extended to databases.

    public function __construct($data_source = "flatfile", $data_options = "email.txt") {
        $this->_db_src = $data_source;
        $this->_db_opt = $data_options;

        $this->_load_members();
    }

    protected function _load_members() {
        // Create the function name to ensure it exists.
        $data_function = "handle_" . $this->_db_src;
        if (!method_exists(&$this, $this->_db_src)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid data source');
        }

        // Build our array of parameters to be sent to our handler function.
        $parameters = array_merge(array('load'), (array) $this->_db_opt);

        // This calls our data function with a load action parameter.
        // This is written to expect the data function to populate $this->members.
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $data_function), $parameters);
    }

    // Most of this is similar to the constructor as far as data handling goes.
    protected function _save_members() {
        // Create the function name to ensure it exists.
        $data_function = "handle_" . $this->_db_src;
        if (!method_exists(&$this, $this->_db_src)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid data source');
        }

        // Set up our data options with a save action.
        $parameters = array_merge(array('save'), (array) $this->_db_opt);

        return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $data_function), $parameters);
    }

    // The heart of the storage engine, designed for CSV data.
    protected function handle_flatfile($action, $filename) {
        switch ($action) {
            case "load":
                // Make sure we can load members.
                if (!is_readable($filename)) {
                    throw new Exception("File: $filename, is not readable");
                }
                // Open our data file and load the information.
                // Populate $this->members as an array just the way we expect it.
                $this->members = array_flip(explode(',', file_get_contents($filename)));
                break;
            case "save":
                // Make sure we can write to the file before we move forward.
                if (!is_writeable($filename)) {
                    throw new Exception("File $filename, is now writable");
                }
                // Convert our array back to a CSV string and write it to the file.
                $status = file_put_contents($filename, implode(',', array_flip($this->members)));
                // If we failed to write to the file make sure something is done before we continue.
                if (!$status) {
                    throw new Exception("Writing to file failed!");
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown action called on data handler.");
        }
    }

    // converts email addresses to lowercase to avoid duplication.
    // should add a regex filter here to ensure that we have a valid address
    protected function _sanitize_email(&$email) {
        $email = strtolower($email);
    }

}

function show_form() {
    echo '<form method="post" action="">' . PHP_EOL
       . 'Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"> <br />' . PHP_EOL
       . '<input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">' . PHP_EOL
       . '</form>';
}

if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $list = new MailingList();
    $status = $list->remove_email($_POST['email']);

    switch ($status) {
        case MalingList::EMAIL_OK:
            echo "<p class='success'>Your email was successfully removed.<p>";
            break;
        case MailingList::ERR_EMAIL_INVALID:
            echo "<p class='error'>The email address provided was invalid.</p>";
        case MailingList::ERR_EMAIL_NOTFOUND:
            echo "<p class='error'>The email address provided was not registered.</p>";
        default:
            show_form();
    }
} else {
    show_form();
}
```

Comment: I went a little beyond the scope of the question, but I had thoughts that I felt obligated to inform you on and didn't know how to express them other than in code.

Comment: how did you learn to type like this lol, its genius :D#

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php It's a fairly basic class, aside from the construct allowing for extension by creating a new handler.  My ideal is to abstract all of the details you don't want to be concerned about.  By doing that, we took the data layer out of the way and focused on the desired functionality.  We then went back and added the necessary functionality to make it work by adding a simple data layer of flat files.

Comment: will edit original question to post code correct

Comment: ive cracked it mate thanks for all you help