# Simple Unsubscribe Script

Tags: php, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple PHP Mailer Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681448/simple-php-mailer-script)

i run a small website and we have had requests for a mailing list....

i have found a simple free script to add email addresses to a txt file - "email.txt" (which is protected) is csv format (email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com,blah,blah,blah)

this script works flawlessly.....

however it is a nuciance to go through this text file to manually remove email addresses when users cancel their subscription to the mailing list.....

i am having trouble creating a simple script to remove email addresses....

so far i have ....

```
    <html>
    <body>





    <form method="post" action="">
    <p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel Newsletter" name="submit">
    </form>



    <?php






    $email = $_POST["email"];


    $text = file_get_contents("email.txt");




    $oldWord = "$email";




    $newWord = "";



    $text = str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $text);




    $fp = fopen('email.txt', 'w');
     fwrite($fp, $text);

    fclose($file);



     ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

this works perfect to remove the email address from the list.....

however i cannot figure out how to echo a comment dependant on whether

```
    str_replace($oldWord , $newWord , $text);
```

is successful at replacing the email address with an empty space....

if the code removes email address i would like "You Have Been Removed From The Flying Shuttle Newsletter."

and if the email address isnt there (code doesnt replace email with empty space)

"The Email Address You Specified Is Not On The Mailing List!"

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It is recommended that you accept answers to questions, such as your previous question, of which this is a duplicate. If you receive an answer that works, accept it. If not clarify the question and elaborate as per any answering users' remarks. If you do not receive an answer that works, do not simply re-post the question, unless the problem has changed significantly enough to warrant a new question (*at which point you may want to reference the former question in the new one*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just compare the length of the returned string.

```
$newText = str_replace($oldWord, $newWord, $text);
if (strlen($newText) < strlen($text)) {
  // Success
} else {
  // Failure
}
```